# only Insertion data in database through AJAX in php.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
[enter image description here][1]     **add.php**
 I am not sure that my data is inserted through ajax or not, can anyone solve my issue.
```

This is my **add.php** file i am inserting the data in database, firstly i have included the database connection file in this file, using POST method to submit data using **mysqli_real_escape_string** to removing special character from string. checking empty fields, link to the previous page, display success message.

```
        <html>
<head>
    <title>Add Data</title>


</head>

<body>
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age =  $_POST['age'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // checking empty fields
    if(empty($name) || empty($age) || empty($email)) {

        if(empty($name)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($age)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Age field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($email)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Email field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        //link to the previous page
        echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Go Back</a>";
    } else { 
        // if all the fields are filled (not empty) 

        //insert data to database   
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO users(name,age,email) VALUES('$name','$age','$email')");



        //display success message
        //echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
        //echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";

}
?>
</body>
</html>




        **add.html**
        In this file i have included all my js file creating a small table for name, age, email. my method is post. i am unable to do this task first time i am using ajax without ajax i insert data many times.
    I am not sure that my data is inserted through ajax or not, can anyone solve my issue.


        <html>
<head>
    <title>Add Data</title>
    <script src="style/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="style/insert.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>



    <br/><br/>
    <p id="alert"><span id="show"></span></p>

        <table align="center" width="25%" border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Age</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" value="Add"></td>
            </tr>


    </table>
</body>
</html>






        **insert.js**
        In this file save input value in variable, my type is POST url is add.php, success function is result, my data is inserted but i am not sure that is this through AJAX or not.
    I am not sure that my data is inserted in database through ajax or not, can anyone solve my issue. 



      $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#submit').click(function()
    {

        var name = $('#name').val(); //save input value in variable
        var age = $('#age').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();


        $.ajax({
            data :{name:name,age:age,email:email}, 
            url  :"add.php", //php page URL where we post this data to save in database
            type :'POST',
            success: function(data){
                alert("Form submitted");
                 $('#name').val("");
                 $('#age').val("");
                 $('#email').val("");

            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Data is inserted using simple PHP Not through ajax.
Because you get input value in ajax with ("#name") means Input id, but you do not define id attribute in an input field.

Comment: i did many changes in my code your suggestion and my under standing can you again see my code where i am doing mistake i have attached debugger screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url:"add.php", //php page URL where we post this data to save in database
            success: function(result){
                $('#alert').show();
                $('#show').html(result);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

- That extra call to `preventDefault` will stop a normal postback from
  occurring (that would be the normal behaviour of your submit button, regardless of the JS event handler).
- Also you are trying to retrieve your fields using IDs
  that don't exist in your markup - you'd need `id="name"` (for
  instance) on your textboxes for that to work. But an easier way to
  get all your form data is simply to use jQuery's `serialize()`
  method, as I've demonstrated above.
- Lastly you had a syntax error (should be `$.ajax` not `$ajax`).

---

Meanwhile, an easy way to tell if it was an ajax request or not is whether your alert was shown or not. If it wasn't, did the page do a full postback? Or is there some kind of ajax error (in your browser's developer tools - console and network tabs)? Perhaps take a tutorial online about debugging JavaScript and ajax, it might help you.

P.S. using mysqli_real_escape_string is not completely safe to prevent SQL injection attacks etc. The best solution is to use prepared statements and parameterised queries. http://bobby-tables.com explains the risks and also shows you how to write queries safely using PHP and mysqli.

Comment: Sir i did which you have mentioned sir but unable to see alert box. how can see alert box on submit button

Comment: If you're unable to see it, do as I suggested and check in your browser's developer tools for any error messages, either in the console or network tabs. What response do you get from add.php? BTW Add.php should _not_ be returning `<html>`, `<body>` tags etc - you can't insert a HTML document inside another HTML document. Remove those. It should return fragments of HTML only, which can go inside your "show" span.

Comment: i updated my code right now i am working on that code above mention, can you again see my code where i am doing mistake i have attached debugger screenshot.

Comment: your debug screenshot is meaningless. You've paused on line 5, so it's inevitable (and surely trivially obvious) that a variable you don't declare until line 7 will be undefined at that exact moment. What did you think you were demonstrating? Learn how to use the debugger. Pause the code _after_ the line you're interested in has been executed, if you want to see the result of that line. Anyway, what you've written bears no resemblance to anything I suggested you should do, so it's hard to see how I can help you. If you try to do my version, which should be more reliable, I can help you better.

Comment: Sir i did, Data submitted successfully through AJAX i did change in add.php. but thanks for your cooperation.